# solve the SDE $dX_t=-\frac{1}{2}\exp\{-2X_t\}dt+\exp\{-X_t\}dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

where $t\in\mathbb{R_+}, X_0=a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $W=\{W_t\}_{t\ge0}$ is the standard Brownian motion.

I've tried exact SDE, linear SDE, and integrating factors but all failed.

Comment: Why do you think that you can find a closed form of $(X_t)$ ?

Comment: This looks like some Ito transformation formula. If $X_t=f(Y_t)$ and $dY_t=b(t)\,dW_t$, then
$$
dX_t = f'(Y_t)b(t)\,dW_t+\tfrac12f''(Y)b(t)^2\, dt
$$
Now try to put the given equation in this pattern,
$$
f'(y)b(t)=e^{-f(y)}\\
f''(y)b(t)^2=-e^{-2f(y)}.
$$
Or take direct inspiration from the structure of the equation and explore $Z_t=\exp(X_t)$.